# Problem on the general solution of the differential equation $ [y+xf(x^2+y^2)]dx+[yf(x^2+y^2)-x]dy=0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This question has stumped me: $$ [y+xf(x^2+y^2)]dx+[yf(x^2+y^2)-x]dy=0  $$

I've tried finding $M_x-N_y$ thinking it would help find some integrating factor, but it came out to be 2 and I don't think I can use an integrating factor now.

I've also tried diving by $x^2,xy$, but I'm not sure how to proceed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that we may have an integrating factor of the form $\mu(x,y)=g(x^2+y^2)$.
$$M=y+xf(x^2+y^2),\quad N=yf(x^2+y^2)-x$$
and we need to have 
$$(\mu M)_y=(\mu N)_x$$
or $$M\mu_y-N\mu_x+(M_y-N_x)\mu=0\tag{1}$$
also $$M_y-N_x=1+2xyf(x^2+y^2)-2xyf(x^2+y^2)+1=2$$
and $$\mu_x=2xg'(x^2+y^2)\quad,\quad \mu_y=2yg'(x^2+y^2)\tag{2}$$
substituting $(2)$ in $(1)$ and simplifying, we have
$$(x^2+y^2)g'(x^2+y^2)=-g(x^2+y^2)$$
or
$$\mu(x,y)=g(x^2+y^2)=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$$
Now proceed.

Comment: Thanks! This was great, but how do we know that the integrating factor in the form of $g(x^2+y^2)$ in the first place?

Comment: @user_9 because of the term $f(x^2+y^2)$

Answer (score 3):

Your equation can be written by collecting like terms as
$$
[y\,dx-x\,dy] + f(x^2+y^2)(x\,dx+y\,dy)=0.
$$
Now you should recognize the first term as the sector area increment $-r^2\, d\phi$ in polar coordinates $(x,y)=r\cdot(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$, while the second factor is completely a function of the radius, $f(r^2)r\,dr$. In total, you get an integrable form by dividing by $r^2$.